# How do I calculate standard error for mortality experiment?

Tags: binomial-distribution, standard-error, mortality

I ran an experiment looking if injuries affect the mortality of crabs over 50 days. How do I calculate the standard error for days when crabs died in relation to the percent mortality? Say I start with 24 crabs. On day 1, 11 crabs die. Day 2, 3 more crabs die. Day 5, 1 more crab dies. The rest survive until the end. That first day I'd have 45.8% mortality but how to I calculate the standard error?

Comment: Have you looked into survival analysis? What exactly do you want to find out?

Answer (score 1):

It is a different story if you want to calculate the life expectancy and its standard error than if you want to calculate "percentage of individuals dead by day $n$" plus its standard error.

If I understood correctly, I should assume it is the latter case. Fortunatelly, when talking about proportions, you can estimate the standard error as $\sqrt{\frac{p(1-p)}{n}}$ where $p$ is the proportion of dead individuals (in a $[0,1]$ rannge, rather than percentage and $n$ is your sample size. The result you get must be multiplied by 100 if you want it as a percentage (see [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution)) for more details. What you are trying to estimate is nothing than the standard error of a binomial distribution divided by sample size in order to make it a proportion)

**INTERESTING NOTE:** You can certainly be sure that it will be lower than $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}$, since $p(1-p)$ will be at most $0.25$

Comment: Thanks very much!

Comment: Yes you are correct in assuming I'm after "percentage of individuals dead by day n". So, using that formula for day one: SE=sqrt(.458(1-.458)/24) * 100 = 10.17%      What about calculating for day 2 when 2 more crabs die. So total of 13 dead. Should I pull out the 11 that already died from the sample size to calculate day 2 standard error?

Comment: That actually depends on what you exactly want to measure. You can calculate the proportion of individuals that die on day 2 from the overall population. Or maybe you want to calculate the chance of dying on day 2 among those who survied day 1. The only condition is that you have to be consistent (use the same data for both estimation of proportion and standard error)